# how to understand the generation of cauchy distribution from uniform distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am learning some basic idea on generating cauchy distribution from uniform random generator $u \in [0, 1]$. I know it was discussed before in [How to generate a Cauchy random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484395/how-to-generate-a-cauchy-random-variable), but during my realization in matlab, I still don't understand how to interpret the results. Here is my matlab code

```
gam = 10; 
x0 = 0;
u=rand(1,1000);
r = x0 + gam.*tan(pi*(u-0.5));
hist(r);

x = -1000:0.01:1000;
y = (1/pi)*(gam./(gam^2+(x-x0).^2));
plot(x, y);
```

I got the result from the hist(r) as

[image]

However, in second part of code where I plot the actual Cauchy distribution, I saw a very different shape as the first figure. Am I missing anything here?

[image]

Comment: You have run the simulation more than once, changed the bin widths, and so on, right?

Comment: Sorry that I just started and I don't get your question. But I have prepared 1000 samples, each followed into [0, 1] as uniform random distribution.

Comment: You should probably set your bins manually rather than letting MATLAB do it in the default manner. For instance you might have a single bin for everything less than -1000, a single bin for everything greater than 1000, and 20 bins for things between -1000 and 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as others have mentioned, you're using the default settings for the [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function. As stated right at the beginning of the documentation, this uses 10 equally-spaced bins by default. Try increasing the number:

```
gam = 10; 
x0 = 0;
u = rand(1,1e4);
r = x0 + gam.*tan(pi*(u-0.5));
hist(r,1e3);
axis([-2000 2000 0 1e4]);
```

The vertical (dependent) axis is in terms of bin counts as this is a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), not a [probability density function (PDF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) plot. However, just being able to specify the number of bins is not very flexible. This one of several reasons why The MathWorks [discourages the use of `hist` and the underlying `histc` in current versions of Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html).

A better, more-flexible alternative is the [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) function, which does a better job of automatic binning even without specifying any additional settings. Additionally, it has [options for easily normalizing the histogram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#inputarg_Normalization) as if it were a PDF, if that's what you're after

```
gam = 10; 
x0 = 0;
u = rand(1,1e4);
r = x0 + gam.*tan(pi*(u-0.5));
edges = -200:10:200;
histogram(r,edges,'Normalization','pdf');
hold on;
x = -200:0.01:200;
y = (1/pi)*(gam./(gam^2+(x-x0).^2));
plot(x,y);
axis([x(1) x(end) 0 1.1*max(y)]);
```

This produces a plot like this:
[image: histogram plot]

Lastly, you can use [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) via Matlab's [`ksdensity`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) function:

```
gam = 10; 
x0 = 0;
u = rand(1,1e3);
r = x0 + gam.*tan(pi*(u-0.5));
x = -200:0.01:200;
y = (1/pi)*(gam./(gam^2+(x-x0).^2));
f = ksdensity(r,x);
plot(x,y,'r--',x,f,'b');
axis([x(1) x(end) 0 1.1*max(y)]);
```

which yields a plot something like this:

[image: ksdensity plot]

More random samples will result in smoother estimates that match your PDF more closely. Be sure to read through the documentation for `ksdensity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to [limit the range of your histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123238/limit-data-values-displayed-in-matlab-histogram). There are a small number of very extreme values in your Cauchy random sample that are causing the histogram to extend over a very large range, and at the same time causing almost all values to occupy one bin. Notice the density plot ranges only from -1000 to 1000. If you impose a similar range on your histogram (even better, make both plots run from -200 to 200), you won't have almost all your values living in one histogram bin, and the shape of the histogram will become more apparent.

Comment: I am trying to limit the range to be -100 to 100, in hisstogram, I still see a uniform distribution but in the real plot, I saw the big different plot.

Comment: What's the problem with generating a row vector of random numbers instead of a column vector of random numbers?

Comment: @Ian: You are right, I am misunderstanding the meaning of the arguments.

Comment: So instead of using hist in matlab, any better way to show the distribution?

Comment: Oh, I think I see your point now, I am trying to increase the number of bins in the hist and it looks better now. One more question, if I use formula $y = x_0 + \gamma*tan(\pi*(u-0.5))$ where $u$ is the random variable generated by uniform distribution, so is $y$ be the random variable but satisfying Cauchy distribution?

Comment: Yes, if $y$ is defined as in your formula, then $y$ will satisfy the Cauchy distribution.